# Automatically adding return types to methods and functions

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

Is there an option to automatically add return types, or at least all me to generate them?

What I want is my methods before PhpStorm generates the return types:

```
function isValid() 
{
    return true;
}
```

After

```
function isValid(): bool
{
    return true;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Using your username (which I enjoy) as inspiration you may want to edit and state you would like to know how to *achieve* this?

Comment: Perfect. thank you.. If you want to create an answer I will mark as best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was already answered at: 
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000163824-Automatically-add-return-type-declarations-

By someone whose profile picture looks like that of [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone). `;-)`

Their answer (quoted and link added) is:

> ... If you are talking about adding ": QueryBuilder" declaration for PHP 7.x -- the "[Php Inspections (EA Extended)](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7622-php-inspections-ea-extended-)" plugin has such intentions/quick fixes; not sure if PhpStorm has the same/similar out of the box.